# Can organocuprates do SN2 reactions with tosylates?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chemoselectivity

In the presence of isolated ketones, can organocuprates add to secondary tosylates in an SN2 fashion without adding to the ketones?

Answer (score 1):

Cuprates (also known as Gilman reagents) do not generally react with isolated ketones. If they did the widely used reaction of cuprates with alpha/beta unsaturated ketone would not work to give the substituted ketone product.

According to this [review](https://europepmc.org/article/med/23956470) alkyl cuprates do react with secondary tosylates to give the expected SN2 product. I have not, however, been able to find an example of this being done in the presence of an isolated ketone